# Send FCM message to specific Google user without need to install an app?

Tags: php, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm doing a tiny personal project involving an Arduino and a PHP backend. I want to send a push notification from the PHP backend to my Android phone using Firebase Cloud Messaging. This question is specifically about FCM - I don't want to use any other services like Blynk, etc. I also do not want to send the notification directly from the Arduino, but rather from the PHP backend.

Can I send a FCM notification to my phone without having to create an app to receive it? I'm logged in with a Google/Gmail account on the phone, and I have no need to target any other users than myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I send a FCM notification to my phone without having to create an app to receive it?

No, this is not possible. It would open users up to some pretty hefty abuse.

In order to receive your notifications, the user must have your app installed.

Mind you, this can be a pretty minimal app, since the default implementation of FCM already displays notifications to the user if the app is not active. So really all you have to do is create an empty app that includes the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK.